# Lexically inclosing type of a class

Tags: java, class

This's how the [JLS 8.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) defines the lexically enclosing type concept:

> A class or interface O is the zeroth lexically enclosing type
>   declaration of itself.
>
> A class O is the n'th lexically enclosing type declaration of a class
>   C if it is the immediately enclosing type declaration of the n-1'th
>   lexically enclosing type declaration of C.

So it's not clear from this definition that any inner class is being considered or just an inner class *of class or interface O*. These are the different concepts, because the last one is defined as follows:

> An inner class C is a direct inner class of a class or interface O if
>   O is the immediately enclosing type declaration of C and the
>   declaration of C *does not occur in a static context*.
>
> A class C is an inner class of class or interface O if it is either a
>   direct inner class of O or an inner class of an inner class of O.

To be more clear let me provide an example:

```
class A{
    class Bar{ } //inner class of class A

    public static void main(String[] args){
        class Foo{ } //inner class, but not an inner class of class A
    }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/8QSDpn)**

The definitioin of immediately enclosing type is being considered any inner class or `inner classes of class or interface O`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `Bar` and `Foo` have `A` as the immediately enclosing *type* declaration. They are on equal footing. The fact that `Foo` is also enclosed by a *method* declaration does not influence this.